# Какое из мест использования if из ниже приведенных решений правильнее?

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
function getMaxSubSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0;
  let partialSum = 0;

  for (let item of arr) { // для каждого элемента массива
    partialSum += item; // добавляем значение элемента к partialSum
    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, partialSum); // запоминаем максимум на данный момент
    if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0; // ноль если отрицательное
  }

  return maxSum;
}

alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, 2, 3]) ); // 5
```

Я думаю это место использование `if`, понятнее и правильнее. После добавления значение элемента к `partialSum`, `partialSum` должно быть проверено. То есть бессмысленно написать `if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0;` после `maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, partialSum);`.

Может быть я ошибаюсь.

```js
function getMaxSubSum(arr) {
  let maxSum = 0;
  let partialSum = 0;

  for (let item of arr) { // для каждого элемента массива
    partialSum += item; // добавляем значение элемента к partialSum
    if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0; // ноль если отрицательное
    maxSum = Math.max(maxSum, partialSum); // запоминаем максимум на данный момент
     
  }

  return maxSum;
}

alert( getMaxSubSum([-1, 2, 3]) ); // 5
```

Comment: Что должна функция выводить? У Вас вывод зависит от значений элементов массива, если будет `getMaxSubSum( [ 2, -1, 3 ] )`, то ответ будет `4`

Comment: Я поняла это. Я имела ввиду есть ли разница в местах использования if? Или без разницы это?

Comment: Разница есть (если вы перед max присвоите 0 переменной partialSum то и в max попадёт 0, а если после max поставить if то этого не будет). Правильность места зависит от логики вашей программы

Comment: А мне кажется нет разницы, т.к. `maxSum` изначально `= 0` и если в `Math.max` сравнивать `maxSum` и `partialSum`, то если `partialSum` будет меньше нуля, то все равно `maxSum` будет в любом случае `0`, т.к. в `Math.max` мы будем сравнивать `0` и `0` или `0` и `меньше нуля`.

Comment: @noname2019 [перед max присвоите 0 переменной partialSum то и в max попадёт 0] - не поняла

Comment: у вас стоит условие "if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0;" если оно выполняется перед Math.max то в случаи его выполнения в Math.max переменная partialSum попадёт с значением 0 как аргумент, а если вы ставите условие после вызова Math.max, то естественно эта ситуация исключается.

Comment: @ostapische Да, и мне так кажется. В любом случае метод Math.max() выбирает большую из чисел по значению. Даже если partialSum будет равен отрицательному числу она вернет 0, так как maxSum равен 0. Но если maxSum при объявлении будет присвоено отрицательное значение то тогда уже будет разница думаю. А так  partialSum просто обнуляется или до присвоении item или после.

Comment: Разницы нет никакой

Comment: @noname Я поняла это. [partialSum попадёт с значением 0], ну и тогда тоже 0(maxSum) будет сравниваться с 0(partialSum). Как и если мы напишем [if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0;] после Math.max, там 0(maxSum) будет сравниваться с  отрицательным числом(partialSum). То есть в любом случае Math.max не вернет отрицательное число. Я проверила с разными числами в массиве, в любом случае( т.е. когда условие  "if (partialSum < 0) partialSum = 0;" стоит или перед Math.max или после Math.max)  возвращает одинаковое значение maxSum.

Comment: @noname Но я думаю должна быть какая-та комбинация чисел в массиве, при котором результаты до и после использования if будут разными.